# `require': cannot load such file -- elance/group.rb while run rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am implementing elace API using 'elance' gem. after install successful bundle now, statr rails server then its give error like :

```
/home/ongraph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/elance-1.0.2/lib/elance.rb:13:in `require': cannot load such file -- elance/group.rb (LoadError)
from /home/ongraph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/elance-1.0.2/lib/elance.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
```

my development env :

ruby ruby-2.1.1-p76
rails 4.0.4
gem 2.2.2

What is the problem?

Comment: Looks like the group.rb file is missing. Check to see if you can find it in the directory specified. If you can't find it, ask the authors where it is.

Comment: thanks, missing file there now, working

Comment: let me know onemore thing. that In lib/elance.rb i have call all methods for elance API using 'elance gem' then how to run this file in rails 4 and getting jobs from elance will save into my local database.